# Importing jar file to ruby script

Tags: java, ruby, jar

This is my ruby script:

require 'java'

require_relative 'hmac_utility.jar'

dec_obj = Java::Hmac_utility::Hmac_utility.new

plaintext = dec_obj.decrypt_ruby(event.get('encypted_secret_pass'), event.get('gcm_key'))

This script sits in a maven project where I've imported hmac_utility jar file.

And this is my java class from the jar file(this is my first time making a jar file not sure how the main method would work if I need to use another function from the class)

public class hmac_decryptor {

```
private static final Charset UTF_8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
private static final int TAG_LENGTH_BIT = 128;
private static final int IV_LENGTH_BYTE = 12;
private static final int SALT_LENGTH_BYTE = 16;
private static final String CIPHER_INSTANCE = "AES/GCM/NoPadding";
private static final String HASH_ALGO = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";

public static void main(String[] args) {
}

public static String decrypt_ruby(String cText, String syslogKey) {
    try {
        byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cText.getBytes(UTF_8));
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(decode);
        byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH_BYTE];
        bb.get(iv);
        byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_LENGTH_BYTE];
        bb.get(salt);
        byte[] cipherText = new byte[bb.remaining()];
        bb.get(cipherText);
        SecretKey aesKeyFromPassword = getAESKeyFromPassword(syslogKey.toCharArray(), salt);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_INSTANCE);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKeyFromPassword, new GCMParameterSpec(TAG_LENGTH_BIT, iv));
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);

        return new String(plainText, UTF_8);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public static SecretKey getAESKeyFromPassword(char[] password, byte[] salt)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(HASH_ALGO);
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 2048, 256);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
    return secret;
}
```

}

Now my question is have I set up the class properly to use as a jar file and in the ruby script have I done it the right way to use the decrypt_ruby method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference Java code from Ruby, your best bet is JRuby. Note that JRuby is basically an alternative to MRI (the C implementation of Ruby), so you will likely need to execute your script differently.

https://www.jruby.org/